# Including windows.h causes an error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013

This is rather bizarre, I have a class I've been building and currently I have this at the top of my file:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
```

Now I need to add windows.h to the mix but as soon as I do that, I get "Error: expected an identifier" on this line:

```
inline uint32_t Hash2(std::string &Key) {
    return (MurMur3::x86_32(Key.c_str(), Key.size(), 2) % (std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() - 1)) + 1;
}
```

the red line appears under the ::max if that matters. As for the function itself, its supposed to use murmur3 to get me a hash that isn't 0.

If I remove

```
std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()
```

and replace it with the constant 4294967295

then it works fine again.

I don't understand why this is happening. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: `#undef min` and `#undef max`

Comment: well that works... why though?

Comment: because windows is evil :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows.h has a very bad habbit of defining macros in it. In particular, it defines min and max. You need to undef those.